# ios - Is it possible to record an App screen and view or delete the recorded file?

Tags: ios, swift, video-recording

The function you want to implement now is to record everything you see in your app when you run a screen recording I would like to add the ability to view or delete recorded files at any time.

I have found a way to record the screen using the Replay kit, AV kit, When the recording is finished, it is saved as a movie in the photo album.

Instead of doing this, I want to add viedo file to the document path folder in the App after the screen recording, to show the file list recorded by date in the table view, and to view or delete the recorded video when clicking the file.

Is this possible?

Comment: If video is saved in Photo Album you probably can find it and show as document in your view. I naver done that, but that seems possible.

Comment: yes , you can do this. I have done similar like this. i was saving my data in documentary Directory.

Comment: shikha kochar - Do you mean that you are using the ability to record the screen of the running app in real time, save it in the document directory, and then import or delete it?

Comment: shikha kochar - If so, can I get some advice on how to implement that functionality?